# how to load css in codeigniter?

Tags: css, codeigniter, load

My page is unable to load the CSS when I am trying to load the page with default controller like this: `//localhost/mysite/`

But when I am trying to load the page like this `//localhost/mysite/index.php/site/index
css` the CSS is loaded perfectly, and I have to create both my css and image folders like this:

Path `C:\wamp\www\tt\assets\css` and all other application paths are in the root path of the 
tt like `c:\wamp\www\tt\application`.

Please give me solution as soon as possible.

Comment: What does your `.htaccess`file look like?

Comment: What do you mean by **path of the tt** here?

Answer (score 1):

you should give read/write permissions to assets folder and you should user this script to link the css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css');?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a .htaccess file in your tt folder. And place this to remove index.php from your url:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And you should be able to access your file directly `<?php echo base_url()."tt/assets/css/cssfilename.css" ?>`